# Custom sort collections in Jekyll

Tags: jekyll

I am creating a Books page in Jekyll using collections, where each book is a .md file in a _books directory, and a books.html file that displays each book following this example:
https://www.colemanm.org/books/

I'd like to display the books in a custom sort order.  Adding the order in _config.yml does not appear feasible as I may have a hundred books on the page.  I can add a "priority" variable in the front matter and sort on that.  However, I am hesitant to use this method in the event that I'd like to change the priority of a book in the future.

Is there a way I can maintain a custom sort, where it is also feasible to easily alter the ordering of any given book (e.g., move book from index position 10 to position 2 while bumping down all those that were previously at position 2 and below)?